# Is there a way to print the value of a variable at breakpoint in Netbeans?

Tags: c++, debugging, netbeans

I would like to see the value of a variable at a certain point.  The project is written in c++ with g++ compiler, gdb debugger, and Netbeans IDE.  When I set a breakpoint, I can see that I can change the action from "Stop" to "Run Script".  Will "Run Script" allow me to print out the value variables, and if so, how?

I have tried running the following code, but the Breakpoint Action changes from "Run Script" to "Stop" after resuming code execution.

```
printf "pkttype is %d\n",pkttype
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I know little about debuggers, and have no knowledge of your IDE, but I don't think you need to use a debugger function to find a variable at a certain point in this case. Assuming I understand the question properly, I suggest figuring out what point in your code corresponds to the point you want to find the variable value, and then having the program output the variable at that point. Like I said, I have very little knowledge of Netbeans, so for all I know what I'm suggesting can't be done in your case, but this is how I generally do variable analysis on my C++ Windows console programs. Hope this helps!

Comment: That definitely would work.  I could also use gdb directly (forego the IDE altogether), but I'm hoping to understand what could be a valuable feature of Netbeans.